# css alignment issue <dl> <dd >

Tags: html, css

When using **<dt>** and **<dd>** one assumes dd has single line definition. In my case I have multiple entries for definition which I *want* to display properly(How exactly will be cleared after watching attached image). Hence, I am using <da> which is css-ed(margin: 0 0 0 21.3%) to *achieve* below style but I'm not satisfied as this leaves me with these problems:

1. line left above first entry(i.e. Mr. A ?).
2. Testing on different sized monitor gives shifted alignment. i.e. on smaller monitor (margin: 0 0 0 22.3%) works!!!
3. Also when I zoom in and out the alignment shifts.(Zoom-in : shifts left, Zoom-out : shifts right)

**Achieved**

[image: Achieved]

**Wanted**

[image]

As I have designed using <dt> and <dd> on several pages it will be good to obtain a solution in this line.

```css
.top-class-name {
margin-left: 25px;
background-color: white;
padding: 0.5ex;
width: 75%;
}


.top-class-name > div {
margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.top-class-name dl {
margin: 0;
}

dl {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

.top-class-name dt{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 220px;
}

.top-class-name dd {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0;
width: 73%;
}

dd {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-start: 40px;
}

.top-class-name dd:after {
content: '\A';
white-space: pre;
}

.top-class-name da{
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 0 0 21.3%;
width: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-class-name">
    <div>
        <dl>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
            <dt>Guest Names :</dt>
            <da>Mr. A</da>
            <da>Mr. B</da>
            <da>Mr. Z</da>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: `<da>` is not a valid HTML tag, is it?

Comment: btw, I happen to be using it in my JSP and its working fine except the glitches mentioned in my ques.

Comment: Yeah, and that's to be expected.  Most browsers will try their best at rendering invalid markup anyway (which sometimes makes it hard to notice missing ending tags because it may look fine in Chrome but break in Firefox :P).  The point of using valid markup is to further ensure consistency across browsers.  For instance, if you started using `<yl>` (in place of `<ul>` or `<ol>`) it would probably work, but it wouldn't have the same padding or margin that the other two do because the browser has no idea what to do with it.  Thus, functionality is undefined and may break in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to isolate the listed items into a container (I used a `ul` in my example) and float the `dt`.  Lastly, it's important to add `overflow:auto` to the container (this creates a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)), which prevents the individual items in the container from flowing around the floating element.

I removed some problematic code in your CSS that may be important outside of the context of this simple example; however, the principle is there.  You seem to describe floated elements and adding the overflow trick should complete the functionality you need.

```css
.top-class-name {
margin-left: 25px;
background-color: white;
padding: 0.5ex;
width: 75%;
}


.top-class-name > div {
margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.top-class-name dl {
margin: 0;
}

dl {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

.top-class-name dt{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 220px;
}

.top-class-name dd {
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0;
}

dd {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-start: 40px;
}

.top-class-name da{
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 0 0 21.3%;
width: 43%;
}

dt {
  float:left;
  clear:left;
}

dd ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-class-name">
    <div>
        <dl>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
            <dt>Guest Names :</dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li>Mr. A</li>
                    <li>Mr. B</li>
                    <li>Mr. Z</li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
            <dt>Other Term :</dt>
            <dd>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>    
</div>
```